# Como executar vários comandos de cmd em VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Sei que dá pra executar um comando do cmd através do VB.Net, com o Shell em VB.NET:

```
Shell("CMD.exe /c {comando cmd aki}")
```

Porém, quando tem que se usar comando como cd, para mudar o diretório, parece não ser possível com o código acima. Explicando melhor, quero executar tipo um arquivo Batch (.bat),
só que não quero usar um arquivo externo, quero usar apenas a applicação em VB.net para isso. Vou dar um exemplo em um pseudo-código:

```
Shell("CMD.EXE /c cd C:\LocalPath")
ContinuaShellAnterior("mkdir Locale\")
ContinuaShellAnterior("cd Locale\")
```

Entenderam? No caso, esse código, iria:

> 1. Acessar o diretório C:\LocalPath
> 2. Iria criar um diretório dentro do diretório C:\LocalPath, chamado de Locale
> 3. Iria acessar o diretório C:\LocalPath\Locale\

Deu pra entender o que eu quero?

Comment: qual o problema em colocar o diretório completo ao usar o `mkdir`?

Comment: Nenhum, só não precisa, pois já vou estar dentro do diretório onde quero cria-lo mesmo. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só colocar um '&' entre os comandos.
No meu caso iria ficar assim:

```
Shell("CMD.EXE /c cd C:\LocalPath & mkdir Locale & cd Locale\")
```

Comment: Isso não funciona em qualquer caso, pois depende do resultado do comando anterior.

Comment: Eu perguntei naquele caso, citado ali em cima, então funciona sim! Pelo menos nesse que eu queria, e é isso que importa!

Comment: É bom que tenha resolvido no seu caso, mas de qualquer forma é importante o aviso, pois outro usuário pode estar procurando a solução para comandos diferentes, e ter um resultado inesperado.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método `Sys()` da biblioteca de classes "SystemExpansion", ela oferece comandos adicionais para namespace System.
Veja o exemplo como usar ele:

```
Sys("Help") ' Vai mostrar os comandos do console...
```

Ou se quiser, você pode usar esse método e invocar ele para colocar o comando:

```
Public Sub Sys(ByVal CmdCommand As String)
    Dim generated As String = (IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\" & IO.Path.GetRandomFileName() & ".bat")
    IO.File.Create(generated).Close()
    IO.File.WriteAllText(generated, "@echo off" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & CmdCommand)
    Shell(generated, AppWinStyle.Hide, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Gostei muito! Porém o outro funcionou melhor :>)

Comment: Obrigado haha :D

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de interação você precisa de um `Process`:

```
dim proc as ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
dim pr as Process
pr=Process.Start(proc)
pr.StandardInput.WriteLine("comando1")
pr.StandardInput.WriteLine("comando2")
```

Segue um trecho mais completo de uma [resposta do SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7860368), veja se ajuda:

```
Dim myprocess As New Process
Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False

myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
myprocess.Start()

Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput

SW.WriteLine("cd /D C:\batatinhas")
SW.WriteLine("comando")
SW.WriteLine("exit")

SW.Close()
SR.Close()
```

Não se esqueça que nestes casos não é para usar `/C` no `cmd.exe`

Comment: Não deu certo comigo! esse process é o componente?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx